# Freezing BERT layers after importing via TF-hub and training them?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I will describe my intention here. I want to import BERT pretrained model via tf-hub function hub.module(bert_url, trainable = True) and utilize it for text classification task. I plan to use a large corpus to fine-tune weights of BERT as well as a few dense layers whose inputs are the BERT outputs. I would then like to freeze layers of BERT and train only the dense layers following BERT. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You mention Hub's TF1 API `hub.Module`, so I suppose you are writing TF1 code and using the TF1-compatible Hub assets google/bert/..., such as https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1

Are you going to have separate run of your program for the two phases of training? If so, maybe you can just drop `trainable=True` from the `hub.Module` call in the second run. This doesn't affect variable names, so you can restore the training result from the first run, including BERT's adjusted weights. (To be clear: the pre-trained weights shipped with the hub.Module are only used for initialization at the very start of training; restoring a checkpoint overrides them.)